# I be calling vs. I am calling

Tags: grammar

I have seen "I be v.-ing" pattern many times, but I don't know how to get this pattern.

What does exactly this mean and when to use it?

Comment: Are you sure it was "**I be v-ing**" pattern?

Comment: Please provide examples.  Also consider the source of who is speaking.  For example, could they be speaking a dialect?  This pattern is not grammatical in *formal* English, but it's common in certain dialects.

Comment: "I be verb with ing" is Black American (African-American) English. It's used in rap music and speech. You do indeed hear it everywhere you hear that variant. "I be goin' now, man." = I'm leaving now, for example.

Comment: "I be . . ." was also commonly used in BrE country dialects, perhaps occasionally today.

Comment: Yes, well, here it's not that, is it?

Comment: @Lambie why not? "v.-ing" looks like a placeholder to me. Your "I be verb with ing" is also BrE country dialect, as I said, and noted in the ELU link below. Please see the question title.

Comment: Do you mean like a pirate accent?  "Oo arrrh, I be drinking me rum, I be!". If you change the rum to "cider" it sounds like a West Country dialect from the UK.

Comment: I be drinkin' me rum, is not the usage here. That shows it is not the same. :) I think the African-American usage through rap out-pervades any other....

Comment: @Lambie - I am not a native speaker of it myself, but "I be going now" is not really correct in African-American Vernacular English as far as I know.  "be ____ing" is an example of the [**invariant be**](https://ygdp.yale.edu/phenomena/invariant-be), signifying a regular, recurring, or repeating action.  "He going to work" = he is going to work right now.  "He be going to work" = he goes to work as a regular practice.  As such, "I be going now" doesn't really make sense, because *now* implies something other than "invariant".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is informal usage, part of a dialect popular in American cities and with people who admire hip hop culture. A few examples:

> I be going to school now.
>
> Girl, you be trippin'!
>
> "You Be Illin" (Run DMC hit)

The phrase is constructed by using the present continuous form but not conjugating the **be**. You probably shouldn't use it in formal writing.

More discussion here: https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/93231/what-dialect-is-i-be-doing-this

Comment: It is specifically African-American. It is not a dialect popular in American cities unless by that you mean that specific community. Others have coopted the usage.

Comment: I think it goes beyond the specific community into the culture at large. A white person who's been saying it his whole life has "coopted" it?

Comment: No, that is the origin of it. There is no doubt about it.

Comment: For example, Eminem or Macklemore.

Comment: Eminem takes everything he has from African-Americans. He is ***the*** poster boy for whites doing rap. That proves my point exactly. Where do you think he got it??????? No African-Americans, no Eminem.

Comment: I dont disagree about the origin, but a lot of white people speak the dialect today. They grew up that way, they didn't coopt it.

Comment: Look, there's zero point in discussing this any further. White people imitate it and learn it. They don't learn it at home. They imitate African-American speech.

Comment: White people and Latinos and Asians learn the dialect from growing up "on the streets" in every major city in the US. And yes, a lot of suburban and rural people have imitated it. It's not exclusively the latter.

Comment: Streets where there are African-Americans. Period, end of story.

Comment: No worries. I just think that given how things are in the states, it's good to be specific here.

Comment: Yeah no problem. I think we both made our points, and happy to agree to disagree, haha. I dont feel that strongly about it. :-)

Comment: @Lambie you seem to have very rigid opinions about "how things are done in the states." Did you ever leave America and hear how other cultures speak?

Comment: @WeatherVane The most likely answer is re Black American English. It is the variety most often "heard". One doesn't go round hearing the other examples. I know a lot about many varieties of English. It's on TV, movies, rap music, in the street. Everywhere. ***So an ELLer is most likely to have heard that and not an English country dialect***. I speak four languages fluently and understand many dialects. Anything else? Have I ever  heard how other "cultures speak". That's a  hoot. Really. I'm a linguist and have my ear glued all the time to how "other cultures" express themselves.

Comment: I would suggest improving this answer by mentioning that the "be x-ing" form differs in meaning from "am/are/is x-ing" in those dialects that use it. It's not used for all instances of the continuous, but specifically for habitual, periodic actions. This is often how you can tell when someone is not a native speaker of this dialect -- they'll overuse "be x-ing" forms in contexts where they aren't appropriate among native speakers to sound "hip" or "street."

Answer (score -1):

*I be X* means you now do X habitually, periodically, or whenever something happens on regular basis - or intends/appears to do so.

> She be going to her mom's house.  (On a regular basis she goes to her mom's house.  Sometimes followed with a clarifying expression like *all the time*, etc.)
>
> I see him be waiting for his friend everyday.
>
> Every time that dog comes around he be running away like he's scared.

In some cases it's meant to call to attention that a behavior is excessive or that the person doing the behavior doesn't realize he/she is making it a habit or that it's in response to something (e.g. for "girl you be trippin', or "you know you be wanting to ask her out.").

Comment: You be leaving now? It is not simple present usually. He be staying at his moms.

Comment: This is reasonably correct but should be clarified to specify that this is part of African-American Vernacular English and not "standard" English.